# Cypress cannot open chrome browser on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, cypress, npm-install

For some strange reason 'npx cypress open' stopped working.

- nodejs version: 11.15.0 (this cannot be changed at the moment, limited by currect dev set-up)
- cypress: 13.6.1

Tried the following:

```
 cypress clear cache
 npm install --save-dev cypress
```

When I run 'npx cypress open' I get the following errow and the browser does not load:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61166/devtools/browser/548f5056-8904-4904-8160-d9eb3737b716
C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\13.6.1\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\lib\plugins\child\run_plugins.js:182
  invoke = (eventId, args = []) => {
         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:760:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\13.6.1\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\lib\plugins\child\run_require_async_child.js:6:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\13.6.1\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\lib\plugins\child\require_async_child.js:26:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
```

Any suggestions on how this can be resolved?

Thanks,
Archie

Comment: Fixed it by updating nodejs [followed the answer that was posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73603763/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-cypress)